# Python colorbar scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a question regarding the colorbar of the matplotlib. I have a surface-plot, which is working fine, and the colors are used correctly. But somehow, the scale of my colorbar is messed up. I think it should go **from 0 to 0.4**. But the actual code gives me **0 to 0.16**. What am I missing here? Strange that the value 0.16 is the square of 0.4.

Here is my plot:
[image]

And of course, here is my code:

```
values_all = zip(*values_all)
x = range(len(values_all[0]))
y = range(len(values_all))
figure = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 7))
ax = Axes3D(figure, azim=-124, elev=40, zlim=(0, 0.4))
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
surface = ax.plot_surface(x, y, values_all, linewidth=0, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.colorbar(surface, shrink=0.4, aspect=10)
plt.show()
```

If I edit my code the following way, the colorbar is scaled correctly, but the plot itself is not colored correctly anymore:

```
surface = ax.plot_surface(x, y, values_all, linewidth=0, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet,vmin=0,vmax=0.4)
```

Results in:
[image]

With other sample data, you can see that this is not only an issue of the plot's borders (The values that are giving the strange peak are between 0.3-0.35):

[image]

Comment: Never used matplotlib however, as you note that 0.16 is 0.4 x 0.4 and you have two 0.4s in your code, have you tried changing one of them (e.g. the `shrink`) to see if that changes anything?

Comment: @elParaguayo good Point. I tried this already. Tried it again just now, but this does really only change the size of the bar. the values remain the same :-/

Comment: OK - then I'll leave to someone who knows matplotlib. Good luck.

Comment: What do you get if you check the max of `values_all`?

Comment: @deinonychusaur it is at about 0.349[...]. There are several values over 0.16

Comment: It is a bit hard without sample data to work with, but could be that this would work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4366663/1099682

Comment: if you need sample data, you could just hardcore a list of 3 lists. each of the list contains 3 values. so something like `[[0.1,0.2,0.1],[0.1,0.35,0.2],[0.3,0.1,0.1]]`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It kind of looks like your plot is using the colorbar shown. Maybe try setting `vmin=0,vmax=0.4` in the `plot_surface` command.

Comment: @Christoph see my edit... very strange

Comment: What exactly do you think is wrong with the coloring? The only odd thing I see are the colors of the spikes on the boundary. I am not sure how mplot3d deals with isolated points like this. Might be a rendering issue. If that is the case, you might try linearly interpolating your data to a finer grid before plotting.

Comment: @Christoph ok I checked this once more. The coloring is also messy in the middle of the plot. I have created some sample data. and will post the result. sec

Comment: @PKlumpp have you found the solution for this? I'm having the exact same problem as you. Thank you